# drag and drop on sharepoint not working, only FROM specific folders like dragging from home folder

Tags: windows, sharepoint, drag-and-drop, office365

As of just recent, All of my users are able to drag and drop all sorts of things from various different folders, but when we try to drag and drop from home or quick access, it won't let us. This is a new issue that started to happen today, it was working fine before.

I've checked permissions, I've tried switching browsers, I've tried having other users with full permissions try (with same results) I've tried changing my permissions back and forth, both in sharepoint, and office 365 as well.